# Scroll function doesnt work on Raspberry screen - Python 3.8

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an existing python Window on the raspberry, which is working. But when I add the thick letter code for a scroll function (from line 7 to 14, Yscroll... to ...mainloop()), the whole window looks empty then, where all the buttons were illustrated before. I want just to add the scrolling function. Thank you for your support.

```
        import tkinter as tk
        from tkinter import *
        from tkinter import ttk


        tkFenster = tk.Toplevel()           
        tkFenster.title("Einstellungen")
        tkFenster.geometry('800x480')
        tkFenster.attributes('-zoomed', True)
 
        Yscroll = tk.Scrollbar(tkFenster)
        Yscroll.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=Y)
        Yscroll.configure(command=Yscroll.yview)
        tkFenster.mainloop()
        
        rowsizelist = []
        einst_reihenanzahl = 1
        if maxschritte <= 6:
            einst_reihenanzahl = 7
        else:
            einst_reihenanzahl=maxschritte+1
        for i in range(einst_reihenanzahl):
            rowsizelist.append(i)
        columnamount = 4
        columnamount = max_ausgaenge + 3
        columnsizelist = []
        for i in range(columnamount):
            columnsizelist.append(i)
         
            
        tkFenster.rowconfigure(rowsizelist, minsize = 10, weight = 1)
        tkFenster.columnconfigure(columnsizelist, minsize = 10, weight = 1)
        btn_zurueckscreen = tk.Button(tkFenster, text = "Zurück", command = Einstellungen_zurueck)
        btn_zurueckscreen.grid(row = 0, column = 0, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = "nsew")
        btn_save = tk.Button(tkFenster, text = "Speichern", command = einst_speichern_double)
        btn_save.grid(row = 1, column = 0, rowspan = 2, columnspan = 1, sticky = "nsew")
        btn_plusSchritt = tk.Button(tkFenster, text = "+ Schritte", command = plusschritte)
        btn_plusSchritt.grid(row = 3, column = 0, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = "nsew")
        btn_minusSchritt = tk.Button(tkFenster, text = "- Schritte", command = minusschritte)
        btn_minusSchritt.grid(row = 4, column = 0, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = "nsew")
        
        
        # hier wird das 2D Dictionary vorbereitet
        IDs = []
        for i in range(maxschritte):
            IDs.append("Schritt " + str(i+1))
        holder_defaultslist = []        
        #print(max_ausgaenge)

        for i in range(max_ausgaenge):
          if i < 6:
            holder_defaultslist.append("Aus. " + str(i+1))
          if i == 6:
            holder_defaultslist.append("Mot.+")
          if i == 7:
            holder_defaultslist.append("Mot.-")
          if i == 8:
            holder_defaultslist.append("Wart.")
        #
        holder_defaults = {}
        holder_defaults = dict.fromkeys(holder_defaultslist, "")
        # print(holder_defaults)
        IDs.append("Warten \n auf extern")

        var_holder= dict.fromkeys(IDs, holder_defaults)
        #print(var_holder)
        kalla = 3
        reihe = 0
        
        vars_rez = []
        for i in range(maxschritte*max_ausgaenge+1): # hier werden Checkbuttonsvariablen erstellt
            vars_rez.append(tk.IntVar())
            rei = int(((i-i%max_ausgaenge)/max_ausgaenge))
            spal = int(i%max_ausgaenge) + 2
            #print(str(rei) +" Reihe +" + str(spal) + " Spalte")
            # print(str(rei) + " ? " + str(spal))
            # print(rez_arr[rei][spal])
            if i<maxschritte*max_ausgaenge: 
                if rez_arr[rei][spal] == 1:
                    vars_rez[i].set = True
                else:
                    vars_rez[i].set = False
            else:
                vars_rez[i].set = False
            #print(vars_rez[i])     
        
        laufer = 0
        
        ent_rez=[]
        for i in range(maxschritte):     # hier wird Entryvariablen erstellt
            ent_rez.append(tk.StringVar())
        ent_rez.append(tk.StringVar()) #für Wartwert
        ent_rez.append(tk.StringVar()) #für Drehwinkel
        for labelz in var_holder.keys():
            # print (labelz)
            if reihe < maxschritte:
                lbl = tk.Label(tkFenster, text = labelz + "\n Zeit(ms)") # hier wird das Label erstellt
                lbl.grid(row = reihe, column = 1, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = "nsew")
                ent = tk.Entry(tkFenster,width = 5, textvariable = ent_rez[reihe]) # hier wird das Entry erstellt, die Breite zur Not wieder weglassen wenns auf dem Touch nicht geht
                ent.grid(row = reihe, column = 2, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = "nsew")
                ent.delete(0, 'end')
                ent.insert(0, rez_arr[reihe][1])  
            else:
                lbl = tk.Label(tkFenster, text = labelz) # hier wird das Label für letzte Zeile erstellt
                lbl.grid(row = reihe, column = 1, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = "nsew")
                
            if reihe < maxschritte:
                for labely in var_holder[labelz].keys():                  
                    chb = tk.Checkbutton(tkFenster, text = labely, variable=vars_rez[laufer]) # hier wird der Checkbutton erstellt
                    chb.grid(row = reihe, column = kalla, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = "nsew")
                    if rez_arr[reihe][kalla-1] == 1:                    
                        chb.select()    
                    kalla = kalla + 1
                    laufer = laufer + 1
                    if kalla == 3 + max_ausgaenge:
                        kalla = 3
                        reihe = reihe + 1
            else:                
                chb = tk.Checkbutton(tkFenster, text = "W a ext", variable=vars_rez[laufer]) # hier wird der Checkbutton erstellt
                #print(vars_rez[laufer])
                global Wartwert
                global Drehwinkel
                print(Wartwert)
                print(Drehwinkel)
                chb.grid(row = reihe, column = kalla-1, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = "nsew")
                #print("wart auf ext vor select"+ str(Wartaufext))
                if Wartaufext == 1:                    
                    chb.select() 
                #print(rez_arr)

                btn_Kalibrierung = tk.Button(tkFenster, width = 4, text = "Kalibrie-\nrung", command = Kalibrierung)
                btn_Kalibrierung.grid(row = reihe, column = 3, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = "nsew")
                btn_Motorplus = tk.Button(tkFenster, width = 4, text = "Motor+", command = Motorplus)
                btn_Motorplus.grid(row = 5, column = 0, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = "nsew")
                btn_Motorminus = tk.Button(tkFenster, width = 4, text = "Motor-", command = Motorminus)
                btn_Motorminus.grid(row = 6, column = 0, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = "nsew")
        
        
                lbl = tk.Label(tkFenster, text = "Warten auf\nmaximal:")              
                lbl.grid(row = reihe, column = 5, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = "nsew")
                ent = tk.Entry(tkFenster, width = 4, textvariable = ent_rez[reihe])
                ent.grid(row = reihe, column = 6, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = "nsew")
                ent.delete(0, 'end')
                #Wartwert = ent_rez[reihe].get()            
                ent.insert(0, Wartwert)

                lbl = tk.Label(tkFenster, text = "Winkel(°)\nvor/zurück")
                lbl.grid(row = reihe, column = 7, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = "nsew")
                ent = tk.Entry(tkFenster, width = 4, textvariable = ent_rez[reihe+1])
                ent.grid(row = reihe, column = 8, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = "nsew")
                ent.delete(0, 'end')
                #Drehwinkel = ent_rez[reihe+1].get()
                ent.insert(0, Drehwinkel)                              
                
                
                btn_Startposition = tk.Button(tkFenster, width = 4, text = "Motor in \n Startposition", command = Startposition)
                btn_Startposition.grid(row = reihe, column = 9, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = "nsew")
                #lbl = Label(tkFenster, text = "Motor im \nUhrzeigersinn")
                #lbl.grid(row = reihe, column = 9, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = "nsew")
                #lbl = Label(tkFenster, text = "Motor gegen \nUhrzeigersinn")
                #lbl.grid(row = reihe, column = 10, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = "nsew")

                reihe=reihe+1    
        # print(vars_rez)
        # lbl = Label(tkFenster, text="Warten \n auf extern")
        # lbl.grid(row=maxschritte, column=1, rowspan=1,columnspan=1, sticky="nsew" )
        # chb = Checkbutton(tkFenster, text = "W a ex", variable=vars_rez[maxschritte*max_ausgaenge]) # hier wird der Checkbutton erstellt
        # chb.grid(row = maxschritte, column = 2, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = "nsew")
        print("varscheckforext=" + str(vars_rez[maxschritte*max_ausgaenge]))
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your window appears empty, because your code never reaches a point where anything other than the Scrollbar has been added to the window.  Are you really not seeing the AttributeError that results from the incorrect Scrollbar configuration?  (You're telling the Scrollbar to scroll *itself*, rather than one of the few widget types that knows how to scroll.)  Even if you fix that, the call to `.mainloop()` will not return until the window is closed, so none of your other widgets can be added until it's too late to display them.

Comment: Good morning, thank you for your comment. I am new to Python and I really dont understand the issue, as I took over an existing code i have to work out. Can you please tell me how to include the other widgets in the code to see the same window but with the scollbar added to it? Thank you very much

Comment: a hint how to get to the solution would be also very helpful

Comment: Scrollbar must be attached to a scrollable widget (Listbox, Text, Canvas, Entry). If you want to make a scrollbar for the entire window, there are questions like this on StackOverflow.

Comment: All code that follows the mainloop call ("tkFenster.mainloop()") is not executed until the window is closed.
It is not clear what the structure of your application looks like. The [tk.Toplevel](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html) window does not need its own mainloop. Usually, the toplevel parent window is some root window ("root = tk.Tk()") with one "root.mainloop()" for all.